# How do I partition, rank and sort data using a pyspark RDD?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I'm using pyspark and have an `RDD` that is the following format:

```
RDD1 = (age, code, count)
```

I need to find the code with the **highest count for each age.**

I completed this in a `dataframe` using the `Window function` and `partitioning by age`:

```
df1 = df.withColumn("rank", rank().over(Window.partitionBy("age") 
\.orderBy(desc("count")))).sort("age", desc("count"))

df2 = df1.select("age", "code", "count", "rank").where("rank = 1")
```

However, I need to find the same result using only `RDD operations`, but I'm not quite sure how to do this. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: Any specific reason to use RDD? because spark data frames function at end convert results to RDD and it is more optimized in terms of performance and complexity compared to use normal RDD.

Comment: I totally agree, it's for a school assignment though so I have to do both RDD and dataframe versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (for pyspark):

```
rdd1.keyBy(lambda x: x[0]).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x if x[2] >= y[2] else y).values().collect()
```

**Where:**

1. use `keyBy(lambda x: x[0])` to convert the original RDD to a pair-RDD with element of `(age, (age, code, count))`
2. use `reduceByKey(lambda x,y: x if x[2] >= y[2] else y)` to find the element with max(count) for each age
3. take `values()` which is `(age, code, count)`

**Note:** this takes only one element in case of ties at the max value

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately at this moment `window functions` without `PARTITION BY` clause move all data to a single partition so it is particularly useful if you have large dataset.

If you don't mind using developers API there you can try `RDDFunctions.sliding` but it requires manual processing.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

val first = rdd.first match {
  case NameValue(name, value) => NameValueWithLag(name, value, value)
}

sc.parallelize(Seq(first)).union(rdd
  .sliding(2)
  .map(a => NameValueWithLag(a(1).name, a(1).value, a(1).value - a(0).value)))
```

[Randomly splits this RDD with the provided weights](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.5/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala)

simplest approach is to convert a RDD to dataframe and perform the operation then
convert it to RDD.

**Dataframe to RDD**

Prior to `Spark 2.0,` `spark_df.map` would alias to `spark_df.rdd.map()`. With Spark 2.0, you must explicitly call `.rdd` first `spark_df.rdd.map()`.